# IE8 before content not displaying

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8, pseudo-element

Here is the link to the offending page: http://www.wrightspecialty.com/brokers-agents-questionnaire.html?view=foxcontact

There's a limitation to the form builder I am using. Can't insert text unless it's a label to a textbox, input, etc. IE9, Firefox, Safari and Chrome all display correctly. IE7 has no support and IE8 has limited.

So I'm attempting to insert copy using the :before pseudo selector. For IE8 and below I'm using Google's javascript. This works for IE7 and not IE8

```
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"></script> 
    <![endif]-->
```

And I'm targeting each element in css as such:

```
    .foxcontainer_brokers div:nth-child(11):before, .foxcontainer_brokers div:nth-child(14):before, .foxcontainer_brokers div:nth-child(17):before, .foxcontainer_brokers div:nth-child(20):before, .foxcontainer_brokers div:nth-child(23):before, .foxcontainer_brokers div:nth-child(23):before, .foxcontainer_brokers div:nth-child(26):before, .foxcontainer_brokers div:nth-child(29):before {
        float: left;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        padding-left: 3px;
        width: 100%;
        font-weight: bold;
        clear: both;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .foxcontainer_brokers div:nth-child(11):before {
        content: "Schools 8211 - Elementary and Secondary Schools";
    }

    etc...
```

Anyone have any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with your `:before` pseudo-element, which IE8 does support. It's with your `:nth-child()` pseudo-class... and your `::before` pseudo-element with double colons, both of which IE8 does not support.

If the IE9 script doesn't work for some reason, perhaps you should try something like Selectivizr + a selector library of your choice (e.g. jQuery). You should also avoid double colons for pseudo-elements if you're trying to support IE8 because it doesn't understand that syntax.

Comment: Selectivizr + Google's IE9 script seemed to do the trick. Selectivizr for IE8 and Google's script for IE7.

Answer (score 1):

IE8 dont support css3 selectors (nth-child)

Comment: My mistake, I've updated the code above. I do have it as single semicolon and it's still not displaying.